# Laguerre's theorem on power of a point w.r.t. an algebraic curve

Tags: geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves

So on Wikipedia article for a power of a point there is a short section about [Laguerre's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point#Laguerre.27s_theorem). The problem is, the article has no references, and whenever I'm trying to Google it the only things I get are either [power diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_diagram) or some different definitions of power of a point w.r.t. algebraic curve, but none of these seem to trace back to Laguerre's work.

So my question is, as expected

> Can anyone give a reference to Laguerre's original work, or at least provide a place where properties of his definition (such as independence of the choice of the circle) are proven?

Comment: I have had a look at the collected works of Laguerre (*Œuvres* vol. 2, Éditions Gauthier-Villars, 1905) and could only find this theorem enunciated, together with many others of the same kind, but not proven.

Comment: It's Theorem 1 here: https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k90212c/f29.item

Answer (score 2):

The source for this theorem is  [Laguerre, *Sur les courbes planes algébriques*, 1865, pg 20, Théorème 1](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k90212c/f29.item).  There the theorem is stated without proof, and then all but forgotten in the mists of history.  The paper is worth a look, whatever your level of French math comprehension.  If I read it correctly, Laguerre defines power of a point $(\xi,\eta)$ w.r.t. to an algebraic curve $f(x,y)=0$ as $f(\xi,\eta)$, up to some multiplicative constant.  This is consistent with the power of a point w.r.t to a circle.

A good place to start the literature search is [Thomas & Porta, *Clifford’s Identity and Generalized Cayley-Menger Determinants*](https://www.iri.upc.edu/publications/show/2362) (there's a download link), which fortuitously came out earlier this year.

The Laguerre theorem is briefly discussed at the end of Section 4, leading to two papers by Neville:

- [Neville, *Products of lengths of tangents and of normals*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3609024), which gives further references in the second and final paragraph.
- [Neville, *The power of a point for a curve*.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3610261), where Laguerre's theorem is stated on the final page, after preliminaries and proof.

Another proof is given in [Coolidge *Algebraic Plane Curves*, pg 176](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonalgebr0000cool/page/176/mode/2up).

Answer (score 0):

I am not allowed to comment so I am posting here.  I found a scholarly journal from Cambridge University entitled "A New Proof of Laguerre's Theorem About The Zeros of Polynomials"

http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FBAZ%2FBAZ33_01%2FS0004972700002951a.pdf&code=2102886a73cf51a49ea5704c1f57a0b3

Journal of Pure and Applied Mathematics - Laguerre, Sur La Théorie Des Équations Numériques

https://ia600401.us.archive.org/24/items/thoriedesquatio00lagugoog/thoriedesquatio00lagugoog.pdf